# how to calculate accuracy per epoch

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am training a model while calculating accuracy for each iteration when i running this line of code:

```
  model = train_model(model,criterion,num_epochs=100,learning_rate=1) # Training the mode
```

I get an error in this line :

```
 epoch_acc = np.sum(np.equal(totalPreds.cpu().numpy(),np.array(totalLabels)))/50000.0
```

**getting error**

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50000,) (0,)

I also change this line by following code:

```
    epoch_acc = np.sum(np.equal(totalPreds.cpu().numpy(),totalLabels.numpy()))/50000.0
```

**also getting error of**

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'numpy'

this is the code for obtaining accuracy per epoch

## Accuracy per epoch

```
    tempLabels = tempLabels.numpy()
    _,totalLabels = np.where(tempLabels==1)                        
    epoch_acc = np.sum(np.equal(totalPreds.cpu().numpy(),np.array(totalLabels)))/50000.0      
    train_acc.append(epoch_acc*100) 
    epochTimeEnd = time.time()-epochStartTime
    print('Average epoch loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch_loss))
    print('Average epoch accuracy: {:.4f} %'.format(epoch_acc*100))
    print('-' * 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues in this code.

1. `totalLabels` is already a numpy array, thus you don't need to do `.numpy()` which belongs to the `torch` module, not the `numpy` one.
2. Your `np.where()` returns a truncated array of indices in second element of the tuple. You probably want: `totalLabels = tempLabels == 1` with a reshaping.

Try to replace it with the following code:

```
totalLabels = (tempLabels == 1).numpy().squeeze()
epoch_acc = np.sum(np.equal(totalPreds.cpu().numpy(), totalLabels))/50000.0  
...
```